# Unit test for race condition

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, thread-safety, race-condition

Consider the code:

```
class TestClass
{
    private bool _someFlag;
    private object _sharedObject = new object();
    private readonly object _syncObject = new object();

    public object Read()
    {
        //lock (_syncObject)
        {
            _someFlag = false;
            return _sharedObject;
        }
    }

    public void Write(object obj)
    {
        //lock (_syncObject)
        {
            _someFlag = true;
            _sharedObject = obj;
        }
    }
}
```

It has race condition issue. When we call `Read()` some thread can call `Write()` between  `_someFlag = false;` and `return _sharedObject;` lines. I am going to fix issue by `lock` operator. But could you please help me to unit test this race condition issue.

I do not want to change `_someFlag` to `public` for test purpose or anything like that.
I want to do something like that:

```
[Fact]
public void RaceConditionTest()
{
    var correctObject = new object();
    var test = new TestClass();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        test.Write(correctObject);
        var assertTask = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var actualObj = test.Read();
            Assert.True(object.ReferenceEquals(correctObject, actualObj), $"Failed on {i} iteration");
        });
        //Thread.Sleep(50);
        var failTask = Task.Run(() => test.Write(new object()));

        Task.WaitAll(assertTask, failTask);
    }
}
```

But how can I be sure that `assertTask` will be started before `failTask`? Or maybe there is another way to unit test this case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Race conditions are likely to be impossible to unit test, either in the positive, and *especially* in the negative.  In order for the code to reliably do what you don't want, you've have to specifically put in synchronization mechanisms that force the operations to happen in a reliable order, so that you can reliably reproduce the undesirable behavior.  But to add in the synchronization to reliably produce the undesirable behavior you've now *forced* the code to behave wrongly; you could just as easily write it to behave correctly, and if you're unsure if you have, you can't rely on the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have stayed with this approach. But still looking for a better way...
This test fails on some iteration, but if you uncomment `lock` operators the test will be passed.

```
class TestClass
{
    private IEventRecorder _eventRecorder;


    private bool _someFlag;
    private object _sharedObject = new object();
    private readonly object _syncObject = new object();

#if DEBUG
    public void SetEventRecorder(IEventRecorder eventRecorder) => _eventRecorder = eventRecorder;
#endif

    public object Read()
    {
        //lock (_syncObject)
        {
#if DEBUG
            _eventRecorder?.Record(nameof(Read));
#endif
            _someFlag = false;
            return _sharedObject;
        }
    }

    public void Write(object obj)
    {
        //lock (_syncObject)
        {
#if DEBUG
            _eventRecorder?.Record(nameof(Write));
#endif
            _someFlag = true;
            _sharedObject = obj;
        }
    }

    public interface IEventRecorder
    {
        void Record(string eventName);
    }
}

public class TestClassTests
{
    private class EventRecorder : TestClass.IEventRecorder
    {
        private string _events = string.Empty;

        public void Record(string eventName) => _events += eventName;

        public string Events => _events;

        public void Reset() => _events = string.Empty;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void RaceConditionTest()
    {
        var correctObject = new object();
        var eventRecorder = new EventRecorder();
        var test = new TestClass();
        test.SetEventRecorder(eventRecorder);

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            test.Write(correctObject);
            var assertTask = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var actualObj = test.Read();
                if (eventRecorder.Events.StartsWith("WriteRead"))
                    Assert.True(object.ReferenceEquals(correctObject, actualObj), $"Failed on {i} iteration");
            });
            var failTask = Task.Run(() => test.Write(new object()));

            Task.WaitAll(assertTask, failTask);
            eventRecorder.Reset();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To test concurrency issues it is best to have all threads waiting at a defined point and then release them all.

```
var threadCount = someList.Length;
var threadsReady = new ManualResetEvent(false);
var threadsReadyCount = 0;   
Task.WhenAll(someList.Select(item => Task.Run(() => worker())));

void worker() {
    Interlocked.Increment(ref threadsReadyCount); 
    if (threadsReadyCount == threadCount)
        threadsReady.Set();
    else
        threadsReady.WaitOne();
    // Do some work...
}
```

Comment: You could probably replace the `ManualResetEvent`+`threadsReadyCount`-counter with a [`CountdownEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.countdownevent).

Comment: used the CountdownEvent instead here https://github.com/copenhagenatomics/CA_DataUploader/pull/236/files#diff-a1b010215fe96ed42a36a69cc93116f5fbee311ecde461342e9c425c2634aae6R26-R34. Note it uses ThreadPool.SetMinThreads, as it affects the runtime a lot if you run out of threads (if it ever finishes).

Answer (score 0):

you can check if assertTask is running or completed before starting failTask:

```
while (assertTask.Status != Running && assertTask.Status != RanToCompletion)
Thread.Sleep(50);
```

Comment: How does this help to test race condition? I need to have both tasks executed simultaneously. If I have assertTask completed I am not able to reproduce race condition.

Comment: the answer to "how can I **be sure** that assertTask will be **started** before failTask" is to check task status like I suggested above. There is no guaranteed way to reproduce race condition. You can only reproduce by running this loop many times, way more than 1000 times